# Configuring reactive messaging in quarkus for the AWS Glue Schema Registry

Tags: quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Having an issue integrating the AWS Glue schema registry with quarkus reactive messaging. I have a property defined as:

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.eligibility.schemaName=<some schema name>
```

Notice the camelcase in schemaName. The Glue schema registry is looking for a value for schemaName but from the log output quarkus seems to be putting that property out in all lower case as schemaname so the default approach for adding additional kafka properties doesn't work.

Is there a way to maintain the camel casing in the properties file or another approach to adding kafka properties to an application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the property segment into quotes to preserve the original case :

```
mp.messaging.outgoing.eligibility."schemaName"=<some schema name>
```

Comment: Using the quotes here's what's shown in the properties for kafka:  {"schemaname"=<value>, . The quotes come across and the property name is lower cased (mp.messaging.outgoing.eligibility."schemaName"=<value>.

Comment: The above was logged from the aws schema registry code. From the kafka producer got this message:  The configuration '"schemaname"' was supplied but isn't a known config. Also, should have mentioned earlier in case there have been changes to the smallrye config I'm using quarkus 1.11.6.

Comment: Quotes should be the way to do, if it didn't work so it's an issue on Smallrye reactive messaging side I think. You can open an issue for this.